# AWS Cognito google signin received x-cache: Error from cloudfront

Tags: google-oauth, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, google-authentication

I am getting 500 internal server error while trying to configure google sign in with my Cognito user pool, steps followed are from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html).
There is no error message in response to the requested API.

I'm finding it very difficult to troubleshoot the issue. Only thing observed from response headers is

> x-cache: Error from CloudFront

The error is from token endpoint URL: **oAuth2/token**

> **Request URL**: https://mydomainurl/oauth2/token
>
> **Request Method** : POST
>
> **Headers**:
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> **Form body**:
>           grant_type: authorization_code
>           client_id: cognito_app_client_id_here
>           code: AUTH_CODE
>           redirect_uri: https://redirect-url
>
> **Received response headers**:
>           access-control-allow-credentials: true
>           access-control-allow-origin: https://mydomainurl
>           cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>           content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>           date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 08:10:28 GMT
>           expires: 0
>           pragma: no-cache
>           server: Server
>           ***status: 500***
>           strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
>           vary: Origin
>           via: 1.1 1111111222333.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>           x-amz-cf-id: **DirdxkYdQojw7EE8fw-_Kta_nHfBIQBN9VpT2qTg3WGoj2a_8yh3RA==**
>           x-amz-cf-pop: BLR50-C3
>           x-amz-cognito-request-id: 97468dc9-8957-4a35-8780-1a7f5d9e3c56
>           ***x-cache: Error from cloudfront***
>           x-content-type-options: nosniff
>           x-frame-options: DENY
>           x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Does anyone know how to resolve the above error?

Where to view any error logs if generated by CloudFront distribution or by

CloudWatch for the above request?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a web app hosted on S3, distributed by CloudFront, with OAuth2 user authentication via Cognito.

In my case, the web app was a single-page application with routing. The app was hosted at https://example.com but my callback URL was at https://example.com**/login**. Since the login process involved navigating away from the app then redirecting back, it resulted in a `404 Not Found` on the S3 side since there was no resource at `s3://example.com/login`, subsequently causing the `x-cache: Error from cloudfront` as seen in the response headers of the original question.

The fix was to edit the CloudFront distribution and [add a custom error response](https://keita.blog/2015/11/24/hosting-a-single-page-app-on-s3-with-proper-urls/), mapping `404 Not Found` to a response path of `/index.html` and response code `200 Ok`.